# Show location points in a tile map with kibi

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash 2.3.1, elasticsearch 2.3.1 and kibi 0.3.2. I have problems visualizing locations in a map with kibi.

I have the following configuration in logstash:

```
input {  
    file {
        path => "/opt/logstash-2.3.1/logTest/Dades.csv"
        type => "Dades"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {  
    csv {
        columns => ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "c11", "c12", "c13", "c14", "c15", "c16", "c17", "c18", "c19", "c20", "c21", "c22", "c23"]
        separator => ";"
    }

ruby {
        code => "
                temp = event['c17']
        event['c17'] = temp[0..1].to_f+ (temp[2..8].to_f/60)
        temp = event['c19']
        event['c19'] = temp[0..2].to_f+ (temp[3..8].to_f/60)

        "
    }

        mutate {
            convert => { 
            "c3" => "float"
            "c5" => "float"
            "c7" => "float"
            "c9" => "float"
            "c11" => "float"
            "c13" => "float"
            "c15" => "float"
            "c21" => "float"
            "c23" => "float"
        }

    }

    date { 
        match => [ "c1", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS", "ISO8601"]
            target => "ts_date"
    }


    mutate {
            rename => [ "c17", "[location][lat]", 
            "c19", "[location][lon]" ]
    }
}


output {
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => localhost
        index => "tram3"
        manage_template => false
        template => "tram3_template.json"
        template_name => "tram3"
         template_overwrite => "true"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

The mapping configuration file (tram3_template.json) is like this:

```
{
  "template": "tram3",
  "order":    1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tram3": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I import de csv file to elasticsearch it seems that all works ok. The output is something like this:

```
{
       "message" => "26/02/2016 00:00:22.984;Total;4231.143555;Trac1;26.547932;Trac2;-338.939697;AA1;-364.611511;AA2;3968.135010;Reo1;0.000000;Reo2;0.000000;Latitud;4125.1846;Longitud;00213.5219;Speed;0.000000;CVS;3873.429443;\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-04-25T14:02:52.901Z",
          "path" => "/opt/logstash-2.3.1/logTest/Dades.csv",
          "host" => "ubuntu",
          "type" => "Dades",
            "c1" => "26/02/2016 00:00:22.984",
            "c2" => "Total",
            "c3" => 4231.143555,
            "c4" => "Trac1",
            "c5" => 26.547932,
            "c6" => "Trac2",
            "c7" => -338.939697,
            "c8" => "AA1",
            "c9" => -364.611511,
           "c10" => "AA2",
           "c11" => 3968.13501,
           "c12" => "Reo1",
           "c13" => 0.0,
           "c14" => "Reo2",
           "c15" => 0.0,
           "c16" => "Latitud",
           "c18" => "Longitud",
           "c20" => "Speed",
           "c21" => 0.0,
           "c22" => "CVS",
           "c23" => 3873.429443,
      "column24" => nil,
       "ts_date" => "2016-02-25T23:00:22.984Z",
      "location" => {
        "lat" => 41.41974333333334,
        "lon" => 2.22535
    }
}
```

But when I try to visualize the location parameter in a map it doesn't show any result:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Why the location point doesn't appear in the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ES mapping file, you probably need to enable the storage of the `geohash` sub-field (defaults to false) as the geohash aggregation cannot work without it.

```
{
  "template": "tram3",
  "order":    1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tram3": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "geohash": true,           <-- add this
            "geohash_prefix": true     <-- add this
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can build a geohash aggregation on the `location.geohash` field

Note that if you want to also index all geohash prefixes, you can also add  `"geohash_prefix": true` to your field mapping.

**UPDATE**

After reproducing the case, here are some more fixes to do:

You need to change the `type` in your `file` input as it will be used as the document type and your mapping specifies that the mapping type is named `dades2` not `Dades`:

```
file {
    path => "/opt/logstash-2.3.1/logTest/Dades.csv"
    type => "dades2"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
```

Your `elasticsearch` output should look like below, namely, `manage_template` should be true and use the full path to your `dades2_template.json` file (make sure to change `/full/path/to` with the actual path name.

```
elasticsearch { 
    hosts => localhost
    index => "dades2"
    manage_template => true
    template => "/full/path/to/dades2_template.json"
    template_name => "dades2"
    template_overwrite => "true"
}
```

The new `dades2_template.json` file should look like this

```
{
  "template": "dades2",
  "order":    1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dades2": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "geohash": true,
            "geohash_prefix": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I have added `"geohash": true` and `"geohash_prefix": true` in the mapping file and the geopoints doesn't appear in the map :(

Comment: Did you wipe out your index and re-create it from scratch + re-indexed your data?

Comment: Yes, I have created a new index with a different name and a new mapping file.

Comment: Did you select the `location.geohash` field in your Kibana aggregation?

Comment: In the buckets I select `Geohash` Agregation and the `location` field

Comment: You might need to kill your Kibana index-pattern and also re-create it from the new mappings in your new index

Comment: When I have created the new index, I've also deleted the old index pattern. However there's no results.

Comment: Can you check if in your new index-pattern in Kibana you see the `location.geohash` field? Also maybe consider taking a larger time interval in your query.

Comment: Yes, in the index pattern I see the `location.geohash` field. I have set a interval of 2 years and the map still remains without results

Comment: Can you see what is the underlying request that kibi sends to ES? Via the browser dev tools (network panel)

Comment: Do you mean this request: '{"size": 0,"query": {"filtered": {"query": {"query_string": {"analyze_wildcard": true,"query": "*"}},"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"ts_date": {"gte": 1388559247586,"lte": 1461650947586, "format": "epoch_millis"}}} ],"must_not": []}}}},"aggs": {"2": {"geohash_grid": {"field": "location","precision": 2}}}}`

Comment: What do you get when you execute that request directly against ES? `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/_search -d '{"size": 0,"query": {"filtered": {"query": {"query_string": {"analyze_wildcard": true,"query": "*"}},"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"ts_date": {"gte": 1388559247586,"lte": 1461650947586, "format": "epoch_millis"}}} ],"must_not": []}}}},"aggs": {"2": {"geohash_grid": {"field": "location","precision": 2}}}}'`

Comment: Note that I've tried the exact same steps in my Kibi and I could get a location point to show on the map. Are you sure you have data in your index? what does `curl localhost:9200/_cat/count` yield?

Comment: In the request that you say I have to replace `index` for my index? In the second one I receive the following line: `1461738341 08:25:41 86471`. Note that I can see the other values indexed in the dashboard...

Comment: Yes, you need to replace "index" with your real index name

Comment: I receive the following response: `{"took":603,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":86455,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"2":{"buckets":[]}}}`

Comment: Oh, I think I know. First increase the precision (to 10 or 12) in the options of your geohash aggregation. You will see markers on the map afterwards. For the long term you should also add `geohash_prefix: true` to your template (see my updated answer) so that each location is indexed for any geohash precision (including 2). Then you need to to reindex your data again.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but you mean that I have to add more decimals to my latitude and longitude?

Comment: No, just modify `tram3_template.json` the same way as in my updated answer (i.e. with `geohash: true` + `geohash_prefix: true`). Then wipe your index again and rebuild it with your data. It should be good after that.

Comment: I have updated the file but still there's no result :(. Where can I increase the precision?

Comment: In the "Options" tab next to the "Data" one in your aggregation panel.

Comment: I only can change the precision to 7. And there's no result.

Comment: Elastic search show this error when I change the precision: `[Wildside] All shards failed for phase: [query_fetch]
RemoteTransportException[[Wildside][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query+fetch]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size": 0,"query": {"filtered": {"query"15: {"query_string": {"analyze_wildcard": true,"query": "*"}},"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"ts_date": {"gte": 1388559247586,"lte": 1461650947586, "format": "epoch_millis"}}} ],"must_not": []}}}},"aggs": {"2": {"geohash_grid": {"field": "location","precision": 2}}}}]]; `

Comment: `nested: QueryParsingExeption[Faled to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
 at [Source: [B@49c5703d; line: 1, column: 43]];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size": 0,"query": {"filtered": {"query"15: {"query_string": {"analyze_wildcard": true,"query": "*"}},"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"ts_date": {"gte": 1388559247586,"lte": 1461650947586, "format": "epoch_millis"}}} ],"must_not": []}}}},"aggs": {"2": {"geohash_grid": {"field": "location","precision": 2}}}}]];`

Comment: `nested: QueryParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
 at [Source: [B@49c5703d; line: 1, column: 43]];`

Comment: `ed": {"query"15: {"que` <-- this doesn't look like valid JSON. Can you restart Kibi just to check?

Comment: kibi show this message: `g   [09:44:28.880] [info][listening] Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5606
  log   [09:44:28.936] [warning][query_engine] Template [kibi-json-jade] already exists
  log   [09:44:28.945] [warning][query_engine] Template [kibi-table-handlebars] already exists
  log   [09:44:28.949] [warning][query_engine] Template [kibi-table-jade] already exists`

Comment: That's normal. Just restart Kibi, please

Comment: Yes, I have restarted and show the message above :)

Comment: And your query is still failing?

Comment: Now the elasticsearch log doesn't show any error. But in the tile map there's no result

Comment: Would you mind sharing your `Dades.csv` file (or a few lines thereof)? I'd like to reproduce your case in my local environment.

Comment: Yes, no problem! Where can I send you the file?

Comment: Can you gist it? Dropbox? Any other file sharing service?

Comment: Yes, I could send you by dopbox

Comment: I see points around Barcelona :-) Can you run this and let me know what you get `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/tram3`?

Comment: I have changed the index tram3 for dades2. But this is the result: `{"dades2":{"order":1,"template":"dades2","settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"1"}},"mappings":{"dades2":{"properties":{"location":{"geohash_prefix":true,"type":"geo_point","geohash":true}},"_all":{"enabled":false}}},"aliases":{}}}s`